# Is it possible to triple boot given the following partition state?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, kali-linux, dual-boot

I have the following partitions on my drive:
[image]
I have researched online that it's not possible to have more than 4 primary partitions. I am not sure these are primary partitions, so will I be able to install windows as triple boot, I have Ubuntu and Kali dual booting as of now. If no, what can I do to be able to do so.

Comment: Set up a virtual machine and test there. If you're a newbie, what are you using Kali for?

Comment: @Kusalananda That's the catch. I had to install kali for a workshop (and yes installing in Vm wouldn't have worked). Now I am trying to triple boot. Isn't it possible?

Comment: Out of interest, what kind of workshop uses Kali?

Answer (score 2):

The restriction of only 4 primary partitions, and indeed the entire concept of *primary partitions* applies only to the classic MBR partitioning scheme.

Systems that use UEFI will normally use GPT partitioning scheme, in which there are no primary nor extended partitions; all partitions are equal, and the maximum limit will be 128 or more. So if your system uses GPT partitioning, you could add as many UEFI-bootable operating systems as your free disk space allows, and triple/quadruple/n-tuple boot.

In `gparted`, click on `View` -> `Device information` and then look at the `Partition table:` row to identify the type of your disk's partitioning scheme.

If you want to install Windows as any other than the first installed OS on the system, you might want to pre-create the partitions needed by Windows to match the layout described in [this Microsoft document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions) and then proceed very carefully through the choice of the installation destination in the Windows installer: it tends to offer "overwrite the whole disk and install only Windows on it" as the first choice, and any other options may be behind some "advanced options" selection.

Comment: I would like to add to this that a hard disk should only contain one EFI System Partition that is common to all operating systems. And yes, you can have more than 128 partitions, bazillions in fact, if you enlarge the partition table from the usual 128 entries.

Comment: ... assuming that your system firmware and the operating system(s) support such an extension, of course. Although the GPT standard can allow such an extension, the implementations might not support it in practice. But even 128 partitions should be plenty for most uses.